# How to clone integer with protobuf

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

i have a problem with cloning of integers, here is the dummy class i used

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllFields)]
public class Ac
{

    private int _ao = -1;

    public int AO
    {
        get
        {
            return _ao;
        }
        set
        {
            _ao = value;
        }
    }
};
```

when i clone it when AO is zero i get value of -1
when i try to add default attribute, i get the correct item, but in some properties when it remains -1, i get 0

Comment: it seems that the problem occurs when i add SkipConstructor = true - which force it to be always 0

Answer (score 1):

This relates to the default values. For reasons lost in the depths of time, protobuf-net assumed zero defaults in v1. You can turn this off on the type-model, but the easier option is to tell it that the default is -1 by adding `[DefaultValue(-1)]` to the field. You can also disable the constructor during deserialization (`[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor=true)]`, but personally I find this less pleasing.

Turning off the zero-default behaviour is more potentially wide-ranging.

Comment: but when i am adding skipconstructor it skip the default value and use 0 for the int values

Comment: @li-raz yes, they were meant as *alternative* options, not *cumulative* options